# Trouble using numpy.load

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have the following data, written in python 2, that I'd like to load to a python 3 file.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([{'a': np.array([1., 2., 3])}])
np.save('data.npy', x)
```

My first attempt was this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.load('data.npy')

UnicodeError: Unpickling a python object failed
```

After playing around with the original data I am trying to load, it seems that whenever I have a numpy float inside of a numpy array inside a python dictionary, I get the error. I can load a dictionary, I can load a numpy array, I can even load a numpy array inside a python dictionary, but as soon as I have numpy floats inside a numpy array inside a python dictionary, I get the error. My second attempt was this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.load('data.npy', encoding = 'bytes')
x

array([{b'a': array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])}], dtype=object)
```

This worked in that I could load the data, but it added a 'b' in front of every key in the dictionary. I was wondering if anyone had any insight into why this problem is occuring and how to fix it.

Thanks!

edit:

it seems like the following solved the problem:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.load('data.npy', encoding = 'latin1')
```

Comment: The b isn't really part of the key. It indicates that the string is a string of bytes. So b'a' is a string with one byte representing the letter a. This is similar to unicode strings, which at least in python 2.x look like `u'a'`.

Comment: There was a comment (I guess it was deleted?) suggesting trying encoding = 'str' instead of encoding = 'bytes'. Encoding = 'str' is invalid, but encoding = 'latin1' seemed to work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default encoding in Python 2 is `ascii`; in Python 3 it is `utf-8`. `latin1` (a.k.a., ISO-8859-1) is a superset of `ascii`. That's why loading `ascii`-encoded strings with `latin1` works and gives the same result as loading it with `ascii`.

Comment: The default value for encoding is 'ASCII', which I tried in the first attempt. But setting the encoding to 'latin1' worked